# Сумма количества символов в каждой строке, с описанием except если строка не попадает под условие

Tags: python, исключения

```
line_count = 0
result = 0
try:
    with open('people.txt', 'r') as file:
        for i_line in file:
            line_count += 1
            length = len(i_line)
        if i_line.endswith('\n'):
            length -= 1
            result += len(i_line)
        if length < 3:
            raise BaseException('Длина {} строки меньше 3 символов'.format(line_count))
finally:
    print('Общее количество символов:', result)
```

Пример результата выполнения.
Содержимое файла people.txt:
Василий
Николай
Надежда
Никита
Ян
Ольга
Евгения
Кристина

Ответ в консоли:
Ошибка: менее трёх символов в строке 4.
Общее количество символов: 48.
Подскажите как правильно реализовать.

Comment: Ну, программа рабочая, что конкретно вас не устраивает?

Comment: Вам надо исключить строки с длиной меньше 3? Или выдать исключение на первой такой строке и остановить программу?

Comment: Ответ в консоли:
Ошибка: менее трёх символов в строке 5.
Общее количество символов: 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('people.txt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    try:
        f = f.readlines()
        size = sum([len(i.strip()) for i in f])
        for x, i in enumerate(f, 1):
            if len(i.strip()) < 3:
                raise BaseException(f'Длина {x} строки меньше 3 символов')
    except BaseException as b:
        print(b)
    finally:
        print('Общее количество символов:', size)
```

Comment: спасибо и красивее код )